# Модифицировать значение перед добавлением std::ostream_iterator

Tags: c++, парсер, stl

Есть строка формата `1,-1,5,2,9,...`. Нужно превратить ее в `std::list<int>`.

```
std::istringstream iss{raw_data};

std::list<int> data{};

using ISIt = std::istream_iterator<std::string>;
std::copy(ISIt{iss}, ISIt{}, std::ostream_iterator<int>(data, ',')); // Не правильно
```

Очень элегантное решение, но одна проблема. Как превратить строку в число перед тем, как его получит `std::ostream_iterator`? Думал унаследоваться от него, переопределив метод `operator=`, но ввиду того, что данный метод не виртуальный, то при объектом полиморфизме внутри `std::copy` все равно будет вызываться метод базового класса.
Да и наследование порождает много ненужного кода.

Есть ли элегантное решение данной проблемы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если идти по тому же пути, т.е. использовать istringstream, copy, istream_iterator, то можно сделать свой фасет, в котором запятая будет "определена" как разделитель, для того, чтобы поток мог разбить числа через пробелы и через запятые.
Не знаю, удовлетворяет такое решение требованиям элегантности или нет.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <list>


struct my_facet : std::ctype<char>
{
    using parent_t = std::ctype<char>;
    my_facet(std::size_t refs = 0): parent_t(make_table(), false, refs) {}
    static const mask* make_table()
    {   
        static mask char_table[table_size];
        static int fake = (std::copy(classic_table(), classic_table() + table_size, char_table), (void)fake, 0);
        char_table[','] |= space;//Запятая теперь разделитель
        return char_table;
    } 
};



std::list<int> make_list(const std::string &source)
{
    std::istringstream ss(source);
    ss.imbue(std::locale(ss.getloc(), new my_facet()));//Цепляем наш фасет к потоку
    std::list<int> result;
    std::copy(std::istream_iterator<int>(ss), std::istream_iterator<int>(), std::back_inserter(result));
    return result;
}


int main()
{
    for (auto e: make_list("1,-1,5,2,9")) {
        std::cout << e << ";";
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. Буду признателен, если подскажете что почитать, чтобы разобраться в окрестности этой темы

Comment: Не уверен, но посмотрите в книге Николаи М. Джосаттис "Стандартная библиотека C++. Справочное руководство". Думаю, в ней должно что-то быть по этим темам - фасеты, строковые потоки, итераторы ввода-вывода.